# puppet prioritizing .yaml file

Tags: windows, puppet, system-administration, hiera

Puppet Version - 3.7.5

Hello

I am trying to stop several services using puppet and Hiera yaml files using an array, the issue i got is the randomization. This causes an error for me where it won't stop a service as there is other services dependent on it. so here is the structure of my Hiera file:

```
server::services:
  - 'WAS'
  - 'DNS'
  - 'IISADMIN'
  - 'NetPipeActivator'
  ...
```

So when i run my puppet agent, it successfully cycles through each of the services and stops them but for some, it wants confirmation that we want that service and all associated services to end. I get this error:

```
The following services are dependent on the windows Process Activation
Service service. Stopping the Windows Process Activation Service service
will also stop these services.

Net.pipe Listener Adapter

Do you want to continue the operation? (Y/N)[N]:
No valid response was provided.
```

It then errors and skips that service and carries on with the rest. My first thought was to include Net.pipe service in my yaml file but above the WAS so it will stop it before stopping WAS. Puppet executes the list randomly each time though.

also here is my manifest file:

```
Class windows::services{

  $windowsservices = [hiera_array('server::services')]


  service {$windowsservices:
    ensure => "stopped",
    enable => manual,
  }
}
```

Is there a way around this ? i was thinking of using ordering arrows '->'but as far as i know they cannot be used within an Hiera array.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Hiera will by default return arrays in an undefined order. Once you have the data in Puppet you can use the [PuppetLabs-stdlib](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib) function sort() to sort them if you want.

However, doing a lexigraphical sort may hide your problem, but not solve it. Your actual issue is you have not modelled the relationship between services in Puppet. What you have are services that depend on other services, and you should reflect that using [relationships](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html).

This will make your manifests more verbose, but it will be "correct".

```
class windows::services { 
  service { 'WAS':
    ensure => stopped,
    enable => manual,
  }
  service { 'NetPipeActivator':
    ensure => stopped,
    enable => manual,
    before => Service['WAS'],
  }
}
```

You could also do this, but this is a bad idea because it **assumes** that the resources **will** come from Hiera. If they don't, this will cause a manifest compilation error:

```
class windows::services { 
  $windowsservices = [hiera_array('server::services')]
  service { $windowsservices:
    ensure => stopped,
    enable => manual,
  }
  Service['NetPipeActivator'] -> Service['WAS']
}
```

If you store services you want to stop in Hiera it may be simple to type, but you have no control over any ordering.